# Where to get comprehensive list of tune2fs/tune4fs options per filesystem?

Tags: linux, ext4, tune2fs

tune4fs can use many undocumented (I mean they are not yet in man tune4fs) options for ext4 filesystem. For example, huge_file, flex_bg, dir_nlink, extra_isize and some others. Is there a comprehensive list of them with description what each option does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *would* say that you should look in `/src/linux-2.6/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt` but those options don't seem to be there in the current pull.  So I would search the [ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/), and if you don't find it there, search and/or post on the [ext4 mailing list](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-ext4).